# How to tell what part of a texture on a 3d cube was touched

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, textures, cube

I am writing a rather simple android game and I am implementing `Open GL` to draw a 3D cube that spins and I need to know where the user has clicked on the texture of the cube.

The texture is a simple square bitmap (100x100) that has a smaller square in the center.
Can anyone give some pseudo code on how to tell where the ray correlates to the texture? Or at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: http://android-raypick.blogspot.com/2012/04/first-i-want-to-state-this-is-my-first.html

Comment: http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?&lo=TP&from=&to=en&a=http%3A%2F%2Fovcharov.me%2F2011%2F01%2F14%2Fandroid-opengl-es-ray-picking%2F